# No Persistence Provider for EntityManager named foo

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

Yes I've already searched here for this question but I have this problem after the researches.

So, I'm making a simple standalone project, containing only Entities and DAOs.
I'm using IntelliJ.

EDIT: My DB connection informations are good, I'm sure. And I've got another project (GWT) and I'm using the same method -> it works

My META-INF folder is in the root src folder, so this is my persistence.xml:

```
`<persistence-unit name="jpa">
    <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->
    <class>ejbpersistance.entities.User</class>
    <class>ejbpersistance.entities.Comment</class>
    <class>ejbpersistance.entities.Article</class>
    <properties>
        <property  name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejb"/>
        <property  name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"  value="root"/>
        <property  name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"  value="root"/>
        <property  name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>`
```

and this is my code:

```
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    if(emf == null)
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa");
    return emf;
}
```

I tried with Hibernate provider, Eclipse provider but always this problem.
Can someone help me ? And if I missed something in another topic concerning this issue, I apologize for the time loss.

Comment: Is there any JPA implementation on the classpath? Hibernate jars, EclipseLink jars, OpenJPA jars on the classpath of your app?

Comment: I'm using Maven and yes -> Hibernate implementation

Comment: Then persistence provider should be `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`, but as far as I can remember, this is not even necessary. Post your stacktrace for better help

Comment: I've cleaned my Maven dependancies and added OpenJPA. Then, changed my persistence unit name to "ejb-jpa". Now, the errors occurs after ! Something's wrong in my Dao.....

Answer (score 1):

The location of the persistence unit is the issue here.

1. check if persistence.xml is in your classpath: 
   If it is non-Java EE application(j2SE)

   The jar file or directory whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml 
   file is termed the root of the persistence unit.please check classpath location in your IDE, Eclipse: Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> ****.
2. check if hibernate provider is in your classpath
   once you can try to uncomment the provider line in your P.xml file
   **org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `persistence.xml` is in the `META-INF` directory and the class path includes the META-INF *parent* directory.

You also didn't show the complete `persistence.xml`. The surrounding `<persistence>` tag must include the proper namespace, e.g.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence">
...
</persistence>
```